# Kernel of sheaf morphism of coherent sheaves is coherent in the general case

Tags: sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

I'm trying to see that if $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ are coherent sheaves of $\mathcal R$-modules over some topological space and $\phi: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf morphism, then $\ker \phi$ is a coherent sheaf. I'm working with the definition that a sheaf is coherent if it is locally finitely generated and any sheaf of relations obtained from it is also locally finitely generated. My attempt goes as follows:

$\ker \phi$ is already a sheaf. Let $x\in X$; we find an open neighborhood $x \in U$ on which we have sections $F_1, \ldots, F_q \in \mathcal F(U)$ locally generating $\mathcal F$. This means that for $y \in U$ we can write $f_y \in F_y$ as $\sum_i g_{i,y} F_{i,y}$ with $g_{i,y} \in \mathcal R_y$ and since $\phi_y$ is $\mathcal R_y$-linear and $\phi$ commutes with taking stalks, we have that:
\begin{align*}
 f_y \in (\ker \phi)_y &\Leftrightarrow \sum_i g_{i,y} \phi_y(F_{i,y}) = 0 \\
  \Leftrightarrow \sum_i g_{i,y} (\phi(F_i))_y = 0 
  &\Leftrightarrow (g_{1,y}, \ldots, g_{q,y}) \in \mathcal R(\phi(F_1), \ldots, \phi(F_q))_y
\end{align*}
Since $\mathcal G$ is coherent, $\mathcal R( \phi(F_1), \ldots, \phi(F_q))$ is locally finite, so by shrinking $U$ if necessary we know that there exist $G_1, \ldots, G_n$ generating $\mathcal R(\phi(F_1), \ldots, \phi(F_q))_y$ at every $y \in U$. Then we can write a $(g_{1,y}, \ldots, g_{q,y}) \in \mathcal R (\phi(F_1), \ldots, \phi(F_q))_y$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n h_{i,y} G_{i,y}$.

I don't see how to proceed from here; how do I get the sections of $\ker \phi$ which locally generate it?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact definition of a sheaf of relations, but if your definition matches the standard definition you may refer to the proof in [tag 01BY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BY) of the stacks project.

Comment: @KReiser What I call $\mathcal{R}(\phi(F_1), \ldots, \phi(F_q))$ is what is called there $\mathcal{K}$. But I don't know how to show that the kernel of $\phi$ is indeed as they claim the image of the composition $\mathcal{K} \rightarrow \oplus_i \mathcal{O}_U \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$. This is the question I ask at the end: knowing the sections $G_i$ which generate $\mathcal{K}$, how do we obtain the sections which generate $\ker \phi$?